# Automatically expand fold when going to a line number

Tags: vim, macvim, folding

Is there a way to unfold code when going to a line number? For instance I type `:35` where line 35 is folded, then I have to unfold that section manually to actually get to that line. I would like to type `:35`and have that code then unfolded automatically and my cursor put on line 35 without any further key presses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the `35G` command instead of `:35`, you can achieve this with the following mapping:

```
"[count]G       Also open fold under cursor when supplying [count] (i.e.
"               jumping to a particular line, not the end of the
"               buffer). Use [count]|gg| if you don't want this.
nnoremap <expr> G (v:count ? 'Gzv' : 'G')
```

For `:35` itself, this would be hard to achieve. You would have to intercept the `<CR>` via a `:cmap <expr>`, check the typed command via `getcmdtype()` and `getcmdline()`, and, if it's a number, manipulate the command, i.e. append `normal! zv` to it; like this:

```
cmap <expr> <CR> getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() =~ '^\d\+$' ? 'normal! zv<CR>' : '<CR>'
```

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>zv</kbd>. From `:help zv`:

```
    View cursor line: Open just enough folds to make the line in
    which the cursor is located not folded.
```

While this command could probably be triggered automatically in some way, I have not come across it yet. Using the command as-is has served me well, though.

Comment: Combining this into `:au CursorMoved * :normal zv` should do the trick.

Comment: @MailenM: That will open any fold you move over, even when moving with `j` / `k` -- I doubt this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Define a new command mapping. In this example, I chose <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>:

```
:nmap \gz gg<Bar>zO
```